# Internship paid vs unpaid on CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, united-states

I have interned in two companies while I was conducting my undergraduate studies, one of the internships was unpaid and the other covered transportation expenses.

My question should I mention in my CV that these internships were unpaid or voluntary?
And does this issue make a difference in the eyes of the graduate admissions committee?

The nature of the internships is related to my undergraduate studies (general computer skills), but not very related to my research topic I want to peruse.

Comment: Just a suggestion... don't be so quick to mark an answer as "accepted", as it reduces the likelihood that you'll get other answers. I would leave it as unaccepted for at least a day or two to allow others the chance to see the question and respond.

Comment: @eykanal♦  Thank you for your suggestion, I will withhold my acceptance till tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you were paid or unpaid is a matter of compensation, which is not something a reviewing committee would care about. All that's important is that your credentials were strong enough to earn you the internship. Whether you were paid or not is irrelevant to the strength of your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To me it's *very* relevant. "*It's not about the money. It's about sending a message.*" What message? you may ask. It's not the same that some guys are willing to pay you as some guys accepting your free work, the difference is huge. Also, it's not the same committing to your work to the extent of working voluntarily for free when compared of working for a salary, which most of the people do much more gladly.

However, **I would not mention that**, again because "*It's not about the money. It's about sending a message.*" And in this case whatever the message is, you don't want to send it. This is not going to be used in your favor, and it can be perceived negatively (in either of both cases). Therefore it is some information not to tell (unless you are explicitly asked) so that people reading the CV can focus on whatever you want them to focus, which will be your skills as the best possible candidate (on any plausible universe!).

Then you can play the card of: "I'm committed" (thus expensive) or "I'm expensive" (thus expensive) or whatever card you may want, either to get the job, a better salary, more responsibilities, a plant in the window or whatever.